# Why does OpenFlow select rule with lower priority?

Tags: networking, network-programming, sdn, openflow, openvswitch

If I have these two rules installed on a switch, which one should be executed according to OpenFlow switch specifications? OVS executes the first although the second has higher priority:

First Rule:

```
cookie=0x20000002000000,
duration=14647.575s,
table=0,
n_packets=1297621,
n_bytes=145897910,
idle_timeout=65535,
priority=1,
udp,
in_port=3,
dl_src=02:6d:f3:c1:b4:7b,
dl_dst=02:54:ab:ce:ba:0f,
nw_src=10.10.10.6,
nw_dst=10.10.10.1,
tp_src=46329,
tp_dst=1000
actions=output:1
```

Second Rule:

```
cookie=0xa000004039d1ae,
duration=164.680s,
table=0,
n_packets=0,
n_bytes=0,
send_flow_rem
priority=9999,
udp,
in_port=ANY,
nw_src=10.10.10.6,
nw_dst=10.10.10.1,
tp_dst=1000
actions=set_field:10.10.10.6->ip_src,
output:1
```

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you omit `in_port=ANY` in the second rule? I've never seen in being used to match packets, only to match rules (e.g., in `ovs-ofctl del-flows`).

Comment: You may be right! I actually have two other rules in the exact same way but the in_port is not "any" for those and they're matching correctly. Why would "any" cause a problem like this?

Comment: @pchaigno, you were right, I removed ANY from in_port and replaced it with exact port numbers and now it is working!

Comment: Glad I could help! I've made this into a full-fledged answer for other users going through the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not currently documented, **`ANY` as a value for `in_port` should only be used for flow mod (delete) and flow stats requests**. To match packets regardless of their port, you can simply remove `in_port=ANY` from your OpenFlow rule.

---

This behavior is [not documented](http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt), but several places in the source code mention it. First, `OFPP_ANY` is [defined as a synonym of `OFPP_NONE`](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/2f2b904f9e28afaff3dfb7adaa62b96c0d144ace/include/openflow/openflow-1.1.h#L80). [The comment above](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/2f2b904f9e28afaff3dfb7adaa62b96c0d144ace/include/openflow/openflow-1.1.h#L74-L75) mentions that it should only be used to match OpenFlow rules. Finally, [the comment for `OFPP_NONE` definition](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/2f2b904f9e28afaff3dfb7adaa62b96c0d144ace/include/openflow/openflow-1.0.h#L52) states that `OFPP_NONE` means `Not associated with any port`.

I think this should be properly documented or `ovs-ofctl` should reject that value when used improperly. I'll raise the issue on the ovs-dev mailing list and will update this post depending on the answer.